# pass as callback the address of a static method whose signature came by tuple unpacking

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I need to pass a Lambda as callback (in particular for WinAPI). The idea is the following:

1. Store the lambda in a singleton class (every Lambda, also two identical ones, have different types) so it should be safe

   `LambdaSingleton<Lambda_Type>::instance = l;`
2. Pass as callback the address of static method that invokes the lambda instance.

   ```
   template <
       typename Lambda,
       typename Callback_Signature_R,
       typename... Callback_Signature_Args>
   struct LambdaCallbackSupport{

       /**
       *   Callback method
       *
       *   @param  args
       *               The parameters to feed to the lambda
       *   @return 
       *               The return value of the execution of the lambda
       */
       static Callback_Signature_R __stdcall callback(Callback_Signature_Args... args){
           return LambdaSingleton<Lambda>::instance(args);
       }
   };
   ```

I already have a working class for extracting informations about functions at compile time es:

```
template<
    typename C,
    typename R,
    typename... Args>
struct Traits<R(__stdcall *)(Args...) const>{
      //various typedefs for R, tuple of args, arity etc..
};
```

So i would get something like this:

```
//Example lambda
int toBeCaptured = 8;
auto lambda =
    [&](std::string& str) -> size_t{
        return toBeCaptured + str.length();
    };

typedef decltype(lambda) Lambda;

//Expected callback signature
typedef size_t(__stdcall *CallbackSignature)(std::string&);

//Configure a callback support and pass its method
typedef Traits<CallbackSignature> callbackTraits;

typedef LambdaCallbackSupport<
    Lambda,
    callbackTraits::Result_Type,
    callbackTraits::Args_Tuple_Pack> CallbackSupportType;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  //How to unpack the tuple without actually have the arguments??

//Store the lambda instance statically
Singleton<Lambda>::instance = lambda;

//Pass the callback
void* pFunc = &CallbackSupportType::callback;

//Simulate invocation of callback
std::string str("may work?");
size_t ret = (*pFunc)(str);
```

Since i need only to let the compiler generate a callback class specialization (and not actually invoke its method) **how can i apply the iterative unpacking technique proposed in other questions on  this site?**

Thank you

Comment: Something similar, but using overload and `decltype` magic instead of using any `std::tuple`: http://ideone.com/ROiFwi

Comment: I don't think your `Singleton<Lambda>::instance = lambda;` statement should work, since a closure type has a deleted copy assignment operator (5.1.2p19).

Comment: @aschepler My Singleton implementation's instance is a std::function object parametrized with the traits offered by the class above when deduced from the operator() of Lambda.. I have unit tested the Singleton and  seems working

Comment: Ah, I thought `Singleton<Lambda>::instance` had type `Lambda`, since your code never shows the type.  But a `std::function` of a correct type would work, yes.

Comment: Why would you want to use a Singleton here?  (Why would you want to use a Singleton anywhere?)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Because in order to pass a method as callback it must be static, and a static method has not access to instance data.

Comment: That's no reason to use a singleton. If you want a class with static data and static functions then use a class with static data and static functions, you don't have to use a singleton. Singleton is a specific (very bad) pattern describing how to restrict creation of an object and provide access to it. Just because you have static data doesn't mean you're using a "singleton" (and that's a good thing, singleton sucks.)  Your question says you use a singleton "so it should be  safe" .. huh? Singleton doesn't make things safe, it makes things hard to test, hard to make correct and hard to fix.

Comment: Probably you're right, but still the instance is single and must be accessed statically.. Which name you suggest?

Comment: What you have is sometimes called [Monostate](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MonostatePattern). But I just call it a class with static members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general answer to your question (how to do tuple unpacking), parameter packs can only be generated *implicitly* in the context of *template argument type deduction*, so if you want to "unpack" a type `tuple<T1, ..., Tn>` into a sequence of types `T1, ..., Tn` you have to instantiate that tuple and supply that instance in input to some function template:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void unpack(tuple<Ts...> const&) // Now you have an argument pack...
```

However, considering what you want to achieve (get a WinAPI callback from a lambda), I would not rely on tuples, and rather use a free function template. That can be done without introducing many levels of indirections and wrappers. Here is a possible simple solution:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template<typename F>
struct singleton
{
    static void set_instance(F f) { instance.reset(new F(f)); }
    static std::unique_ptr<F> instance;
};

template<typename F>
std::unique_ptr<F> singleton<F>::instance;

template<typename F, typename... Ts>
typename std::result_of<F(Ts...)>::type __stdcall lambda_caller(Ts... args)
{
    if (singleton<F>::instance == nullptr)
    {
        // throw some exception...
    }
    else
    {
        return (*(singleton<F>::instance))(args...);
    }
}
```

This is the framework. And this is how you would use it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //Example lambda
    int toBeCaptured = 8;
    auto lambda =
        [&](std::string& str) -> size_t{
            return toBeCaptured + str.length();
        };

    singleton<decltype(lambda)>::set_instance(lambda);
    size_t (__stdcall *pfn)(std::string&) = &lambda_caller<decltype(lambda)>;

    std::string str = "hello";
    int out = pfn(str);
    std::cout << out;

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't mind macros and want to simplify that further for some usage patterns (like the one above), you can add a macro like this:

```
#define get_api_callback(lambda) \
    &lambda_caller<decltype(lambda)>; singleton<decltype(lambda)>::set_instance(lambda);
```

That would change your `main()` function into the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //Example lambda
    int toBeCaptured = 8;
    auto lambda =
        [&](std::string& str) -> size_t{
            return toBeCaptured + str.length();
        };

    // As simple as that...
    size_t (__stdcall *pfn)(std::string&) = get_api_callback(lambda);

    std::string str = "hello";
    int out = pfn(str);
    std::cout << out;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is still safe to configure an uniue_ptr from the lambda object and the use it after it has been out of scope???
(example scenario in the LPSTART_THREAD_ROUTINE fed to the ::CreateThread api)

Comment: @MrAduer: a *copy* of the lambda object is being assigned to the `unique_ptr`. mind this: `instance.reset(new F(f));`

Comment: Although if the lambda captures a local variable reference, like in this example, it's still wrong to use the callback after that referenced variable is out of scope.

Comment: @aschepler: true, I agree. but that's not related with this specific design I believe. if you create a reference to an object, you must always make sure that the reference doesn't outlive the referenced object.

Comment: @AndyProwl: That's clever, letting the conversion to function pointer deduce `Ts...`.  Well done.

Comment: @aschleper Yes in such situation synchronization is required to wait the thread before exiting the scope.. I have put a random capture just for showing that capturing is a requirement

Comment: however thanks both to aschleper and to andy because both of you have put some nice ideas, but i promote the andy aswer because the missing thing was:
"..so if you want to "unpack" a type tuple<T1, ..., Tn> into a sequence of types T1, ..., Tn you have to instantiate that tuple and supply that instance in input to some function template"